# Access properties from array of objects inside looping in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I have an array with a combination of strings and objects. Then I tried to display the properties of the array based on the key in a loop. Is it possible to do this in typescript?

This is the sample code:

```html
const arr = [
  { name: 'John' },
  'Amber',
  { name: 'Cathrine' },
  'Louis',
  { name: 'Mike' }
]

arr.forEach((item, key) => {
  if (typeof item !== 'string') {
    console.log(item.name) // Works
    console.log(arr[key].name) // Doesn't work, losing type
  }
}
```

Please check this link to run the code:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwTAvDA2gKBjA3jMOAWwFMAuGAcgCkQALMSmAXwBpsqBBIgIxIUrsc+QqQqUAwnCh0EASzAkmbDpQAyIAK5yIgjiOLkqAWTkBrJS0wBdTJkQIAdADMQCAKJxgdABQ+5UCRErDAWAJ4AlKgAfHgccs4wPlBhAA4kIIkBQTAAhCholNDyYADmlFG4HDigkCAANiSO9SCl-oFEjqIkUQD0vTAA6m5mENUwtRANTS1tDujh1l2GfQMAIiAkEIywAO4jIS0gEAqlMCnpHMyYzEA

I really appreciate your help, Thank you!

Comment: It's not at all clear what the problem is. If you fix the snippet so that it's runnable and doesn't have the syntax error, both console.logs print the same thing. Also unclear what "losing type" means there.

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply, please check this link to run the code. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwTAvDA2gKBjA3jMOAWwFMAuGAcgCkQALMSmAXwBpsqBBIgIxIUrsc+QqQqUAwnCh0EASzAkmbDpQAyIAK5yIgjiOLkqAWTkBrJS0wBdTJkQIAdADMQCAKJxgdABQ+5UCRErDAWAJ4AlKgAfHgccs4wPlBhAA4kIIkBQTAAhCholNDyYADmlFG4HDigkCAANiSO9SCl-oFEjqIkUQD0vTAA6m5mENUwtRANTS1tDujh1l2GfQMAIiAkEIywAO4jIS0gEAqlMCnpHMyYzEA

Comment: As you can see I am losing type when trying to access the 'name' property from the array. I need it to access directly from the array, not from the looping.

Comment: Not sure why you'd ever need to do that but in that case either `const myItem = arr[key]; if(typeof myItem !== 'string') { console.log(myItem.name); }` or `console.log((arr[key] as {name: string}).name)`

Comment: I am using vue with typescript and need to modify an object from the array by adding new properties or modify some properties value. I can't modify the properties directly inside the looping, because it will lose reactivity. That's why the modification should be done directly from the array, the looping is only used to loop the array and get the keys.

Comment: Here's the vue code illustration. https://codesandbox.io/s/vuejs-playground-forked-q8mj2?file=/index.js

Comment: The problem is I am losing type when trying to access the property directly from the array.

Comment: why not simply use item.name?

Answer (score 1):

This is how type guards work in TypeScript. They only filter the type of variable that is checked. In your case you are checking for `item` (in `typeof item !== 'string'`) and therefore only `item` is assumed to be not a string.

## Fix

If you want to access `arr[key].name` then store that in a variable, type check that variable with a type guard, and then you are good to go.

Full fixed example:

```
const arr = [
  { name: 'John' },
  'Amber',
  { name: 'Cathrine' },
  'Louis',
  { name: 'Mike' }
]

arr.forEach((item, key) => {
  const member = arr[key];
  if (typeof  member !== 'string') {
    console.log(member.name) // Okay
  }
});
```

Comment: `let menuItem = menu[key] as typeof item`

I'm currently using type assertions as suggested by @Guy Incognito in the comments above, but I think your code is a better solution. What do you think?

Comment: Actually, I've tried your code before but with a different syntax instead of storing the `arr[key]` to a new variable. I directly checked `arr[key]` in the if statement, but it didn't work. Is there an explanation of why it doesn't work?

Comment: `if (typeof  arr[key] !== 'string') { console.log(arr[key].name) }` My previous code was like this. Btw, I really thank you for your answer, it helps a lot.